# Homework IF statements in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I want to make it from KLM, United, and ANA. How do I do that? Thanks

```py
airlines = ['klm', 'united', 'ana']
for airline in airlines:
    if(airline == 'klm' and airline == 'ana'):
        print(airline.upper())
    else:
        print(airline.title())
```

I want it to show:
KLM,
United,
ANA

Comment: You must use `or`, not `and`.

Comment: `airline` cannot be equal to `'klm'` *and* `'ana'` *at the same time*…

Comment: Because both cannot be true ***at the same time***. The loop checks each value *individually*. You'll effectively end up with `if 'klm' == 'klm' and 'klm' == 'ana'` in the first iteration…

Comment: oh, thanks. I get it now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use or-statement:

`if airline == 'klm' or airline == 'ana':`

or `in` keyword:

`if airline in ('klm', 'ana'):`

Answer (score 2):

Or `if airlines in ('klm', 'ana'):`